# Build vNext CodedUI Item Deployment - items specified in .testsettings not being copied

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, coded-ui-tests, tfs-2015

I have a CodedUI test suite. I'm attempting to use a B-D-T workflow in TFS 2015 R2 to deploy the test .dlls to a machine group and execute them.

The tests rely on a couple files - an html start page and an XML file.

First, I attempted to have the tests just run from the bin folder OR where they're deployed onto the machines in the machine group. No suggestions I found on SO or on the first 3 pages of google worked. Whenever I ran a test locally it would copy the test dlls to the TestResults folder and execute from there.

Then, I attempted to use a .testsettings file to deploy the files with the .dlls into the TestResults folder. I still truly don't understand why this is the best or only solution - if I can just execute from the Bin please let me know how, but it does work - locally.

Now in TFS 2015 when I deploy my testing software to the test agent(Member of the machine group), I can see my supporting files exactly where they should be in the test drop location. Then, the test starts. A temp folder is created in a byzantine region of AppData, where only the .dlls and config are copied - not the files specified in the .testsettings file! The testsettings file is specified in the "Run Functional Tests" task, which I reached by browsing to the correct file in source control.

I can provide any information you require. This should be so simple but it has been an enormous headache.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration you need to setup where *you* copied the files to on the remote machine using a "Windows Machine File Copy" task executed by the agent. You need to make sure all the files needed to run are copied to the server.

[image]

Then in your `.testsettings` file specify which of the files *you* copied over you want to deploy to the temporary test context directory. Only files already copied to the test agent can be selected here.

The File copy task would look something like:

[image]

Comment: the files I needed to copy initially to the agent are correctly moved using this task. After the "Windows Machine File Copy" where I move the built software + artifacts to the machine group, everything is present on the test context directory in an identical structure to my local machine.

Once the test run starts, mstest copies the .dlls to a crazy nested folder in AppData and attempts to run the test. However it doesn't copy the other files like it does locally.

Comment: Then you may be facing a bug. I suggest filing an issue on the VSO-Agent-Tasks project to get the team to look at this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues